# pass array in Helm values property

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I would like to pass array as property in yaml (values file) in Helm. What I tried:

1. Attempt.

   ```
   elasticsearch:
     uri: "[\"127.0.0.1:9200\",\"127.0.0.2:9200\"]"
   ```

   Error:

   > ReadString: expects " or n, but found [, error found in #10 byte of
   >   ...|RCH_URL":["127.0.0.1|..., bigger context
   >   ...|{"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL": ["127.0.0.1:9200","127.0.0.2:9200"],"LOGS_ENV_PREFI|...
2. Attempt. According to [official helm site](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1987) how to pass array

   ```
   elasticsearch:
     --set uri={127.0.0.1:9200,127.0.0.2:9200}
   ```

   With error:

   > error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 15: mapping values are not
   >   allowed in this context
3. Attempt.

   ```
    elasticsearch:
      uri: 
      - 127.0.0.1:9200
      - 127.0.0.2:9200
   ```

   Failed with the same exception as 1.

EDIT:
Actually in my case the helm values were not used in YAML file then, so I needed another format and finally solution was to pass uri as string with single quote:

```
 elasticsearch:
   uri: '["127.0.0.1:9200","127.0.0.2:9200"]'
```

Nevertheless @Marcin answer was correct.

Comment: Helm Rendering of values from values.yaml to config.yaml :

values.yaml :

sites:
  - dataprovider: abcd
  - dataprovider: xyzx
config.yaml :

     sites:
 {{ toYaml .Values.sites | indent 10 }}

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You pass an array of values by using either the old fashioned json way:

```
elasticsearch:
  uri: ["127.0.0.1:9200", "127.0.0.2:9200"]
```

or the way introduced by yaml:

```
elasticsearch:
  uri: 
  - 127.0.0.1:9200
  - 127.0.0.2:9200
```

You can then access the values in Helm templates using `range`:

```
Uris:{{- range .Values.elasticsearch.uri }}
{{.}}{{- end }}
```

resolves to:

```
Uris:
127.0.0.1:9200
127.0.0.2:9200
```

Comment: just a note: what you define as the `old fashioned json way` is also yaml, just in one line

Comment: Fwiw, I needed to add a `-` to make a valid list in helm.

```{{- range .Values.elasticsearch.uri }}
- {{.}}
{{- end }}```

Answer (score 25):

Helm Rendering of values from values.yaml to config.yaml :

*values.yaml*:

```
sites:
  - dataprovider: abcd
  - dataprovider: xyzx
```

*config.yaml*:

```
sites:
  {{ toYaml .Values.sites | indent 10 }}
```

Comment: This worked for me after a small change -- the first line of output was indented 12 spaces instead of 10; I had to fully left justify the second line above to get the expected output.

Comment: One could also write it on one line as `sites: {{ toYaml .Values.sites | nindent 10 }}`. `nindent`  adds a leading newline.

Comment: Yep we can do these changes as suggested on the requirement of the output.