# How to use boolean and array variable in yaml?

Tags: arrays, kubernetes, yaml, boolean, argocd

I'm having a problem in replacing/substituting a boolean and array variable in yaml. I'm working in argocd yaml file.

```yaml
values:
          files: 
             - 'values.yaml'
             - 'values-stage.yaml'
          automated:
            - name: prune
              type: boolean
              value: true


valueFiles: {{values.files}}   ##Should receive array </code>

prune: {{values.automated.prune}} ##Should receive array </code>
```

How can I put values.files in valueFiles and values.automated.prune to prune?

Comment: I think you are looking for helm template.
Check it out <https://stackoverflow.com/a/58030379/2854252>

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [*anchor/alias*](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#71-alias-nodes) feature can handle this.

```yaml
# example.yaml

values:
  files: &files 
    - 'values.yaml'
    - 'values-stage.yaml'
  automated: &automated
    - name: prune
      type: boolean
      value: true


valueFiles: *files
# It seems there is no 'values.automated.prune' field.
valueAutomated: *automated
```

I have tested it with [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/):

```sh
yq eval '. | explode(.)' example.yml
```

which gives:

```yaml
values:
  files:
    - 'values.yaml'
    - 'values-stage.yaml'
  automated:
    - name: prune
      type: boolean
      value: true
valueFiles:
  - 'values.yaml'
  - 'values-stage.yaml'
valueAutomated:
  - name: prune
    type: boolean
    value: true
```

***NOTE***: YAML aliases can reference only the node that has an anchor on it, not a specific *entry* of the node.